# Как получить сигнатуру процедуры перед ее вызовом?

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, metadata, cx-oracle

Допустим, есть процедура:

```
procedure proc (i_value in number, o_value out varchar2) is
begin null;
end proc;
```

`OUT` параметры, которые передаются в функцию `callproc()`, должны быть инициированы одним из типов:
`cx_Oracle.NUMBER`, `cx_Oracle.STRING` итд.

Обычно переменная, например, с именем `out_value`, получит `o_value` процедуры и перед передачей должна быть определена таким образом:

```
out_value = cur.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
```

А как быть, если сигнатура процедуры заранее неизвестна?
Есть ли способ получить типы данных `OUT` параметров процедуры перед ее вызовом?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [cx_Oracle: Is there a way to get a stored procedure signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64716158) от участника [@p1ka2So](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9607483/p1ka2so)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64716158

Answer (score 4):

В cx_Oracle нет встроенного API `describe procedure_name`.

Надо предварительно запросом получить метаданные из представлений словаря данных `USER_PROCEDURES` и `USER_ARGUMENTS`. Запрос может выглядеть так:

```
select a.position, a.argument_name, a.in_out, a.data_type    
from user_procedures p
join user_arguments a on a.object_id=p.object_id
where p.object_name='PROC' and object_type='PROCEDURE';
/

  POSITION ARGUMENT_NAME    IN_OUT    DATA_TYPE                     
---------- ---------------- --------- ------------------------------
         1 I_VALUE          IN        NUMBER                        
         2 O_VALUE          OUT       VARCHAR2
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64722743) от участника [@Christopher Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799035/christopher-jones)</sub>